# aws s3 ls - how to recursively list objects with bash script avoid pagination error

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pagination, ls

I have on premise AWS S3 like storage. I need to list all files on specific bucket. When I am doing it at the top of the bucket I am getting error:

```
Error during pagination: The same next token was received twice:{'ContinuationToken':"file path"}
```

It happens when two many objects needs to be listed I think. This is something wrong at storage side but there is no cure for that right now.

I did a workaround for that and run S3 ls in the bash loop while. I manage to prepare a simple loop for different bucket where I have a much fewer number of objects. That loop were operating deep inside where I knew how many dirs I have.

```
./aws  --profile us-bucket --endpoint-url https://endpoint:18082 --no-verify-ssl s3 ls  us-bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/ | tr -s ' '| tr '/' ' ' | awk '{print $2}' | while read line0; do ./aws  --profile us-bucket --endpoint-url https://endpoint:18082 --no-verify-ssl s3 ls  us-bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/${line0}/| tr -s ' '| tr '/' ' ' | awk '{print $2}' | while read line1; do ./aws  --profile us-bucket --endpoint-url https://endpoint:18082 --no-verify-ssl s3 ls  us-bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/${line0}/${line1}/| tr -s ' '| tr '/' ' ' | awk '{print $2}' |while read line2; do ./aws  --profile us-bucket --endpoint-url https://endpoint:18082 --no-verify-ssl s3 ls --recursive us-bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/${line0}/${line1}/${line2}/;done;done;done > /tmp/us-bucket/us-bucket_dir2_dir3_dir4_dir5_dir6.txt
```

I would like to write loop which go from the top or root (how you prefer) and list all files (no matter how many dir we have on the path) from the last dir in the path going up to avoid appearing:

```
    Error during pagination: The same next token was received twice:{'ContinuationToken':"file path"}
```

Any help/clues appreciated. Thanks.

Br,
Jay